# C to MIPS conversions

Tags: c, set, mips

```
int MyArray[30]; 
int n = 2;
MyArray[0] = 1;
MyArray[1] = 1;
do{
MyArray[n] = MyArray[n-1] + MyArray[n-2];
n++;
}
while(n < 30);
```

While I was doing this I got stuck on how i can recursively call the function without the use of return address $ra or $sp since the code doesn't actually return anything.

This is my work so far :

```
    #s1= Myarray[0]
    addi $s0, $0, 2  #$s0=n=2
    addi $t0, $s1,0 
    addi $t1,$0,1 
    sw $t1, 0 ($t0) #Myarray[0]=1
    addi $t0,$t0,4
    sw $t1, 0 ($t0) #Myarray[1]=1
    add $t0,$s0,$s1 #MyArray[n]= Myarray[0] +n
    Loop:
    addi $t2,$t0,-4
    addi $t3,$t0,-8
    lw $t4,0 ($t2)
    lw $t5,0  ($t3)
    add $t5,$t4,$t5
    sw $t5, 0 ($t0)
    addi $t0, $t0 ,4
    addi $s0,s0,4
    slti $s6,$s0,30
    beq #s6,$0,Exit
    j loop 
   Exit
```

Comment: I don't see any relation between the title, code and the question.

Comment: Show your effort first? also why do you think you need to recursively call it? why don't you just `jmp`?

Comment: Recursive function call is the same as any other function call. `$ra` is used to hold the return address, not the return value (`$v0` is the register used to return a value). Show us your MIPS code.

Comment: The function in your question isn't recursive. In fact, strictly speaking, it isn't a function at all, just some code…

Comment: @texasbruce You mean *branch* :)

Comment: @m0skit0 It is a type of jmp, but just conditionally :)

Comment: @texasbruce Actually no, branch is PC-relative and used for iterations, jump is absolute and used for function calls or far calls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code

```
sw $t1, 0 ($t0) #Myarray[0]=1
addi $t0,$t0,4
sw $t1, 0 ($t0) #Myarray[1]=1
add $t0,$s0,$s1 #MyArray[n]= Myarray[0] +n
```

should be

```
sw $t1, 0 ($t0) #Myarray[0]=1
addi $t0,$t0,4  #update 't0' to point to Myarray[1]
sw $t1, 0 ($t0) #Myarray[1]=1
addi $t0,$t0,4  #update 't0' to point to Myarray[2]
```

The error is in the last line. Note that `$s1` points to the array, and `$s0` has the value 2, so `t0=s1+s0` points `t0` to the wrong address. You really want `t0=s1+(s0*4)` since each `int` is four bytes.

However, since you've already updated `t0` to point to `Myarray[1]` (in the second line), you can just update it again (in the fourth line).